# How to use QueriesTableAdapter in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, tableadapter

In Visual Studio 2013, I have created a new query in the Data Set Designer.   I did this by right clicking and selecting Add -> Query...   I have the query the way I want it and have saved it.   I now have QueriesTableAdapter with my query named qryListing listed under it.

When I exit the Data Set design mode and go back to the code in my form, how do I execute that query and loop through the results?

Comment: This is very, very broad.  SO is not a tutorial site to teach you everything from A-Z.  You need to do your own research.

Comment: I did 3 hours of trying different things and searching the internet.   If you can point me to specific documentation, I will read it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a data set named dsetMain and inside that I defined a query named fnGetSettingVal that takes 2 string parameters and returns a scalar string. I can run that query and put the result in the variable sRepServer with the following code

```
Dim sRepServer As String = ""
Dim taQuery As New dsetMainTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter
sRepServer = taQuery.fnGetSettingVal("Reports", "ReportServer")
```